# Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server. But I had removed OpenVPN

Tags: internet, openvpn, 20.10

I have uninstalled OpenVPN but my log is full of the error "Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server." and "openvpn@server.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/openvpn: No such file or directory"

Comment: Can you provide error log ?

Comment: The error is "Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server."  and "openvpn@server.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/openvpn: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have uninstalled openvpn but systemd file is not removed.

You can remove it by following below instructions.

```
sudo systemctl status openvpn@server.service
```

It will show status as failed and also print systemd script location starting like
`/etc/systemd/system/` or `/run/systemd/system/` or `/lib/systemd/system/`.

Remove openvpn systemd file. Use path according to openvpn systemd script path in your system.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/systemd/system/openvpn@server.service
```

Comment: It didn't worked, `Unit openvpn.service could not be found`

Comment: In your case, it looks like name is openvpn@server.service. I have edited answer.

Comment: It worked, thank you!!